# Using switched outlet to power a wall controller

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, receptacle

I have a Lutron RadioRA2 keypad that needs power and I want to put it where I currently have a switch for an outlet. I swapped it in and it works if I have a load attached to the outlet. In my case a fan not turned on.

I want to de-hack this. Outlet is 1/2 switched, 1/2 always on. In picture below, top is not switched: black/white. Bottom switched: red/white.

Can I achieve what I want? I can get new outlet, keep tabs.

Would I:

- Connect black/white to new outlet
- Pigtial whites (neutral) together
- Pigtail red solo

???

[image]

Comment: That is correct. (with unbroken tabs) Write it up (the bit after "would I:") as an answer (yes you can do that here...)

Comment: Other than this outlet, is there any other light in this room?  Will it be controlled with a switch? (Doesn't need to be this switch).

Comment: There is an 3/1 circuit for ceiling fan I converted to 2 zone lighting via 2 dimmers. That is working well.

Answer (score 2):

So my real issue was I had my Lutron keypad wired wrong. It needs hot+neutral and I had hot1 (unswitched)/hot2(switched) from switched outlet to keypad. Changing to hot1(unswitched) and neutral in my wallbox has me up and running.‍♂️

Comment: Be happy that 2 hots didn't fry it!

Comment: I know! Lutron stuff is so good.